# Detect coded targets of concentric ring in image recognitionimage

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing

I have some images with coded targets of concentric ring (see picture below for an example). The targets are used in the drone survey.

Are there any software/algorithm to automatically detect it? I have googled, but only found it.

[image]

Comment: Yes there are. But I assume that is not what you wanted as an answer, so maybe you need to rephrase. Note that "please suggest algorithms" is off-topic in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to the custom detector of https://picterra.ch/.

Tutorial is available here https://picterra.ch/2019/02/21/build-your-own-ai-detector/

Hope that this helps :)

*Disclosure: I work there, do not hesitate to let me know if you have any questions or issues*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can write the solution in your answer instead of linking out to one.